# Do HP V24i FHD monitors work with Ubuntu Linux?

Tags: hp

I have a relatively new monitor my husband got me 3 months ago.  It is an HP V24i FHD monitor.  I plug it in to my Ubuntu Linux laptop and I can see the background wallpaper, but no taskbar, no mouse, not anything.  If I open an app on the laptop, it doesn't appear on the HP monitor.  I checked HP website.  They only have drivers for Windows.  I contacted HP support and they said they don't support Linux.  Is there any way to get it to work?

Comment: Monitors rarely require drivers unless to support some kind of atypical feature. It seems the display itself is working fine. You should reframe this question to try to solve the actual problem that you are experiencing, because the answer to this question is probably "Yes", and that doesn't help solve your actual problem.  Include more details about the actual problem that you face (no taskbar, mouse etc).  It would probably help as well to include a screenshot. If you've plugged an additional display into a laptop it's probably a secondary display. Try to drag a window over to it.

Comment: You know the difference between "extended (or joined)" and "mirrored" screens? It's all there in your systems settings > screens. Those are your options and currently you have extended where the second monitor is supposed to NOT have anything else than what you see (you can select to have the launcher in that one, invert order, etc., and of course, *move* windows there). With mirrored screens, as the name suggests, you should see the same thing in both. It has nothing to do drivers that aren't required.